# Variable file generated by Vault can't be sourced in a git-sync container

Tags: git, kubernetes, environment-variables, credentials, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to get the git-sync container to authenticate against a private git repository using a token and username retrieved by the Vault injector from a Vault server.

However, I'm getting the following error from the `git-sync` container:

```
E0903 10:30:23.183712      12 main.go:172] "msg"="unexpected error syncing repo, will retry" "error"="Run(git clone --no-checkout -b master https://github.com/my-ser/my-repo.git /tmp/git): exit status 128: { stdout: "", stderr: "Cloning into '/tmp/git'...\nfatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address\n" }"
```

Per the git-sync [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync#parameters) I just need to export these 2 parameters as environment variables: `GIT_SYNC_USERNAME` and `GIT_SYNC_PASSWORD`.

In my deployment I've added Vault annotations to retrieve the secrets, and used a template to generate the environment variables.

Vault generates the file in the container's file system with the data retrieved, but `git-sync` doesn't source the file, hence the complain about not having an username defined.

```yaml
annotations:
  ...
  vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-repocreds: |
    {{ with secret "repos/my-app" -}}
       export GIT_SYNC_PASSWORD={{ .Data.data.github_repo_token }}
       export GIT_SYNC_USERNAME={{ .Data.data.github_repo_username }}
    {{- end }}
```

And then in the pod spec, I just source the file generated by Vault.
I'm using `dot` because git-sync container doesn't have the source binary.

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: git-sync
    image: k8s.gcr.io/git-sync/git-sync:v3.3.4
      args: ['sh', '-c', '. /vault/secrets/repocreds && <entrypoint script>']
```

I've checked the file `/vault/secrets/repocreds` exists in the `git-sync` container.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, but note that Git itself is utterly unaware of containers or git-sync. All Git sees is "oh hey, an https URL, I'll run a credential helper to obtain a user name and password to send" and the credential helper is failing with the error you see.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah, those 2 environment variables in the context of this git-sync container are the ones that will magically feed git with what it needs to clone the repo. I guess my question here is more around the behavior of git-sync. Maybe the command is running before the variables file is sourced.